# How to recover app/controllers on Ruby Rails?

Tags: file-recovery

I accidentally deleted my app/controllers file on Ruby Rails. How would I get it back? I didn't use git init when I first set it up.

Thanks

Comment: Unless you backed up your computer recently I think you are out of luck

Comment: This isn't really a Rails question. You deleted some files and want to get them back, it makes no difference what kind of files they were

Comment: Then is there some sort of way to get app/controllers back? or would I simply have to start a new project?

Comment: You could start a new project and try to just copy the bits that you need...

Comment: Thanks, I just created a new project and it's working fine for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't have to start a whole new project if you've permanently lost your controller file.  You can do a 'rails g controller ControllerName new index show create etc.'

You'll still have to fill in a lot of the logic, but it's better than starting your whole project over.  And for the love of ${DIETY} back up your stuff.